# Confusion about Pointwise Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

If given:

$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
 n^2x^2&\text{if}\, 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
 1&\text{if}\, \frac{1}{n} < x < \frac{3}{n}\\
      \frac{n}{n-3} \cdot(1-x) &\frac{3}{n} \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$

Is the pointwise limit:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0& \text{if}\ x = 0 \ \text{or}\ x = 1\\
 0&\text{if}\, 0 < x < 1\\
\end{cases}
$

I think this because $f_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n(1) = 0$. As $\frac{3}{n}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity, then surely there is a natural number $N$ such that $\frac{3}{n} < x$ when $n \geq N$ which means the limit is $0$ when $0 < x < 1$? I think the limit is $0$ for $0 < x < 1$ since $f_n(x) = 0$ when $\frac{3}{n} \leq x \leq 1$?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that when $x>0$, there is an $N$ so that $n>N \implies \frac 3n < x$. (For example, we can say $N = \left\lceil \frac 3x \right\rceil$.) And then yes, we must have

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n-3} \cdot (1-x) $$

But this does not simplify to zero. $(1-x)$ does not depend on $n$, so we can factor it out:

$$ \begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) &= (1-x) \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n-3} \\
&= (1-x) \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{3}{n-3}\right) \\
&= 1-x \end{align*} $$

So the pointwise limit of the sequence is

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x=0 \\ 1-x & 0 <x \leq 1 \end{cases} $$

(It's not necessary to treat $x=1$ separately, though it is true $f(1)=0$.)

Comment: That makes sense. It is also fine to leave $x=1$ separately right equal to $0$ either way since it gives the same thing?

Comment: Do I need to say that the limit of $f_n(x) = 1-x$ for every $n > N$?

Comment: The limit of $f_n(x)$ is a number which doesn't depend on $n$, so it doesn't make sense to say that.